# Highlight setext-style (asciidoctor/markdown) headers

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Following naive snippet highlights such headers:

```
syn match asciidoctorH1 "^\_s*\n\a.*\n====*"
syn match asciidoctorH2 "^\_s*\n\a.*\n----*"

hi link asciidoctorH1 Title
hi link asciidoctorH2 Title
```

But for asciidoc(tor) it is incorrect. The issue is in length of the dashes -- it should be exactly the same as text above it:

correct:

```
test header
===========

he world
--------
```

incorrect (shouldn't be highlighted):

```
test header
=======

he world
-----------
```

Basically, is there a way to find the length of the text above dashes and apply it to dashes? Or any other way to do it?

[image]

Comment: Not really, it looks for the way to add underlines to text, which is kind of simple.

Comment: @BLayer, I didn't think it was related but I am not an expert so don't take my comments too close.

Comment: Never mind. I didn't post it to start a debate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into the limitations of the regular expression-based syntax highlighting here. Though you can refer to previously matched text ([`:help /\1`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C1)), you cannot assert on the same number of characters or modify (turn all characters into literal `=` matches) with it. The only option I see would be enumerating all likely lengths separately:

```
syn match asciidoctorH1 "^\_s*\n\a.\{3}\n=\{4}$\|^\_s*\n\a.\{4}\n=\{5}$\|..."
```

That probably won't perform well, though :-(

Comment: I was hoping there is a way and it was just me not able to find the right way to do it. Enumeration would be too much for that, probably I will just highlight headers no matter what number of dashes there are.